# RecyclerView disappears when something else is added to the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I've got a tabbed viewpager, where swiping to the next page is disabled. The reason is, inside the fragment, I have a horizontal RecyclerView that should get the touch event.

Fragment XML :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Federal Representatives"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/federalPager"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The problem is this RecyclerView won't show up... unless I delete the TextView.**

At that point it looks like this :

[image]

But If I keep them both, only the TextView shows up, but not the RecyclerView.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TextView` has this attribute:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Which tells it to be as tall as the parent is... so that pushes the `RecyclerView` off the bottom... try changing it to `wrap_content` instead.

Comment: aghhh, thanks @Buddy. I've been looking at this for a half hour.